# Inconsistency between Windows Phone and Emulator

Tags: c#, string, windows-phone-7, emulation, converters

To tell shortly what I experienced; I have a String in a floating number form to be converted into Double. For Windows Phone 7  Device, it can only convert the numbers fractioned with "comma" (e.g. 46,211), For Emulator 8, it can only convert with "dot" (e.g. 46.211). If you do contrastly, one of them crashes.

Why such a simple crappy thing occurs? Anyone noticed this before?

```
void getconditions(string evaulate)
{
    int i = 0;
    string[] evaluatearray = evaulate.Split(new Char[] { ':' });

    foreach (string s in evaluatearray)
    {
        conditions[i] = Convert.ToDouble(s);
        i++;
        if (i == conditions.Length) break;
    }
}
```

So in this code, s contains fractioned number strings, then I convert them into double as shown above.
Thanks

Comment: You should post the code you use for the conversion. I suspect the problem you have has to do with the Culture of the phone/emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're trying to parse the number without specifying the culture. In those cases, the default culture will be used. What happens is simply that the language of the emulator is different of the language of your phone.

As a rule of thumb, you should never call a `.Parse` method without specifying the culture. The same rule applies when converting a number or a date to string by using the `.ToString` method.

```
double number;

// Use the invariant culture when the culture is irrelevant
// (typically, when you are parsing numbers generated by an application of your own)
number = double.Parse("46.211", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

// Use a specific culture in all the other cases:
number = double.Parse("46,211", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB"));
number = double.Parse("46.211", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Comment: Hi, I have added my code, so if I modify my code just as you do, it will be fixed? Then I will try it. Thanks.

Comment: So what should I do exactly, How can I know which phone uses which culture? What if all of them has different cultures, so my application does not work for some phones. Is there any standartized option for this issue?

Comment: @ilerleartik Where do you get the `evaluate` string from? If it's from a service or a website, then it'll probably always use the same decimal separator. If it's from user input, then you have to choose between using the current culture or enforcing one (then you'll have to explain to the user why its input is incorrect). You can safely parse a double by using the `double.TryParse` method, instead of `Convert.ToDouble`. It will return true or false depending on whether the parsing worked, and won't crash the application.

Comment: Evaluate string comes from a variable that I assigned to initially. Avoiding of crashing of application is not a solution for me, because I need that value converted properly. I use it somewhere vital, and it has to be true. So is this a solution: I will use TryParse, if it fails, then I will replace all "." with "," and then I will parse it again?

Comment: And I assign evaluate string as with "." or "," fractioned numbers. For example: String  evaluate = "44,232" , if it fails on the phone, then String evaluate = "44.232"

Comment: @ilerleartik If you can't predict whether the string will use `,` or `.` as decimal separator, either use a second `double.TryParse` in fallback, or just call replace on the initial string: `double.Parse(s.Replace(",", "."), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`